# how to parse stdclass

Tags: php, mysql, sms, stdclass

I have this data as a response:

```
stdClass Object
(
[GetReceiveMessagesResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Messages] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [MessageID] => 63012240
                        [RecipientNumber] => 30006708212212
                        [SenderNumber] => 09379580052
                        [Body] => Esm200aliaranbeigi
                        [ReceiveDate] => 1482389480
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [MessageID] => 63012231
                        [RecipientNumber] => 30006708212212
                        [SenderNumber] => 09379580052
                        [Body] => Esp243محسن قائدی
                        [ReceiveDate] => 1482389454
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

How I can print `Messages` items ?

```
$counter=count($results->GetReceiveMessagesResult->Messages);
```

Comment: `foreach ($results->GetReceiveMessagesResult->Messages as $msg)`

Comment: Improve your question by clearly specifying the programming language which you have used (not just in the tags).

Comment: specify the format in which it should be printed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop

Try

```
foreach ($results->GetReceiveMessagesResult->Messages as $msg)
{
    echo $msg->MessageID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter=count($results->GetReceiveMessagesResult->Messages);
if($counter>0)
{
    foreach ($results->GetReceiveMessagesResult->Messages as $msg)
    {
       echo $msg->MessageID;
       echo $msg->RecipientNumber;
    }
}
```